# Выбрать строки по уникальному столбцу

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
id, login, basic_account, full_name, actual_address, last_change_date
```

Значения в столбце login могут повторятся, значения в столбце last_change_date отражают дату.

Задача: сформировать новую в которой не повторяются login и дата максимальная last_change_date соответствующая login. И соответсвенно id,  basic_account, full_name, actual_address соответсвуют last_change_date

количество строк в итоговой таблице должно быть ровно количеству уникальных значений login.

моя попытка не оптимальна:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (login) AS login2,
(SELECT MAX(last_change_date) FROM users WHERE login = login2) AS last_change_date2
(SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE last_change_date = last_change_date2) AS id
(SELECT basic_account FROM `users` WHERE last_change_date = last_change_date2) AS basic_account,
(SELECT full_name FROM `users` WHERE last_change_date = last_change_date2) AS full_name
(SELECT actual_address FROM `users` WHERE last_change_date = last_change_date2) AS actual_address
FROM  `users`
`users` ORDER BY login2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from users
 where (login, last_change_date)
       in( select login, max(last_change_date)
             from users
            group by login
         )
```